# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el marcador en una gráfica realizada con plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, plotly

Tengo el siguiente script:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

N = 100
random_x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
random_y0 = np.random.randn(N) + 5
random_y1 = np.random.randn(N)
random_y2 = np.random.randn(N) - 5

fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y0,
                    mode='markers',  
                    name='markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y1,
                    mode='lines+markers',
                    name='lines+markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y2,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='lines'))

fig.show()
```

Que me devuelve la siguiente figura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo modificar la gráfica de modo que, la gráfica denominada `"markers"`, en vez de círculos azules, sean triángulos, cuyo símbolo en plotly es "^" o "triangle-up".
Lo intento de diferentes maneras y siempre me devuelve error. Una de ellas es:

```
# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y0,
                    mode='markers', markers = "triangle-up",  name='markers'),
             marker=dict(size=4, symbol='^'))
```

En otra, en lugar de `symbol='^'` he probado con `symbol='triangle-up'`

¿He mirado en Iternet y no encuentro ejemplo que me inspire... ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacerlo?. AGradeceré ayuda.

Comment: probaste con `marker_symbol ="triangle-up"`?

Comment: Añado a continuación la sentencia correcta, acorde con tu acertada sugerencia.

Answer (score 1):

la sentencia correcta queda así:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y0,
                    mode='markers', marker_symbol = "triangle-up",  name='markers') )
```

Comment: si se quiere cambiar el tipo de marcador a cualquier otro aceptado por plotly, se utiliza el argumento `marker_symbol` y se indica ele tipo de marcador. +1